# HtmlAgilityPack XPath returning HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape a website to get data off of it. So far I got it to at least connect to the website, but now when I try to set the text of a textbox with the data, I just get a bunch of:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
```

There are the same number of **HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection** as there is data. Here is my code ( it is a bit sloppy I know ):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string choice;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

        string urlToLoad = "http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(urlToLoad) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";

        Console.WriteLine(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        htmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream(), true);
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            var articleNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/p");



           if (articleNodes != null && articleNodes.Any())
            {
                foreach (var articleNode in articleNodes)
                {

                    textBox1.AppendText(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/p").ToString());

                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();  
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        choice = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }



}
}
```

So what am I missing / doing wrong here? The data should return something like:

```
Warren County Public Schools Closed 
Washington Adventist University Closing at Noon
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: convert the response to string, to see the html and we will tell you what is wrong. Also most of this checks for null are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the issue. I guess I was trying to grab the document node instead of the inner text... Here is code just in case anyone wants it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string choice;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

        string urlToLoad = "http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(urlToLoad) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";

        Console.WriteLine(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        htmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream(), true);
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            var articleNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/p");



           if (articleNodes != null && articleNodes.Any())
            {
                int k = 0;
                foreach (var articleNode in articleNodes)
                {


                    textBox1.AppendText(articleNode.InnerText + "\n");

                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();  
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        choice = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since `articleNodes` already contain the nodes you're interested in, there's no need to call `SelectNodes()` again inside a loop.

Also, you shouldn't need to check for `null`, since `articleNodes` is a collection. It might be *empty,* but shouldn't be `null`.

Try this, accessing the `InnerHtml` (or `InnerText`) property instead:

```
var articleNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/p");

var result = articleNodes.Select(x => x.InnerHtml.Replace("<br><span>", " ")
                                                 .Replace(" </span>", "")).ToList();
```